# Is it tohmat to assume that two people are together?

Tags: women, sin, relationships, men

Is it tohmat to assume that two people are together if you’ve seen pictures of them together? And then tell your nearest about it even though you aren’t 100% sure?

Comment: What do you mean by tohmat التهمة? In Arabic it means accusation which doesn't seem to apply here.

Comment: Yeah I mean accusation because it’s not 100% clear if these people are together so it’s just assuming. Isn’t that to accuse these people?

Comment: you should edit your post and add this information.

Answer (score 1):

**Is it tohmat to assume that two people are together if you’ve seen pictures of them together?**

No this would not be tohmat. Because as @Medi1Saif said, tohmat means accusation. If you are just assuming in your mind, it is not an accusation which has to be verbal.

What you are describing is non-verbal "Zann" (suspicion):

> "Beware of Zann (suspicion), for indeed Zann is the falsest of speech."

**And then tell your nearest about it even though you aren’t 100% sure?**

Verbal "Zann" would be considered an accusation. It is considered the "worst of lies" as shown above.

And considering that this is an accusation approaching Zina, the punishment of a baseless accusation (not a false one, just a baseless one) that could be 80 lashes. Note that it doesn't matter if your 100% sure or 150% sure. You need 4 witnesses:

> As for those who accuse honourable women and do not bring four witnesses, strike them eighty lashes, and never accept any testimony from them after that, and they are transgressors, (24:4)